# How to set --master, --deploy-mode, --driver-class-path and --driver-java-options through Apache Livy?

Tags: apache-spark, livy

I want to set the **master**, spark **deploy-mode**, **driver-class-path** and **driver-java-options** for the Spark job when the job is triggered through Apache Livy without having to restart the Livy server when these settings change.
How to do this since there are no direct options to do this in Livy?

Answer (score 3):

Livy doesn't take `master` and `deploy-mode` as a param in the REST call. These values will be taken from `livy.conf` which would look something like this:

```
livy.spark.master = yarn
livy.spark.deploy-mode = cluster
```

The above configuration mentions that the master is `yarn` and the deploy mode is `cluster`. The `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.driver.extraJavaOption` can be set through livy using the `conf` param.

**An example:**

```
"conf":{ "spark.driver.extraClassPath":"<YOUR_EXTRA_CLASSPATH>",
         "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions":"-Dlog4j.configuration=/app/log4j.properties"}
```

Comment: According to the documentation on this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) , if you set extraClassPath and extraJavaOptions, the JVM has already started and it doesn't make a difference anymore.

Comment: ^ I believe they have mentioned it to be for `client` mode

Comment: Yes. I want to instantiate the Spark job in client mode through Livy. Need a workaround to set all the mentioned properties for the job.